# Removing Html element using extrernal JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML file in which the elements are generated at run time. This file is supposed to be generated again and again hence I have to make changes through external javascript file. Now I want to remove some elements after the page is fully loaded with external javascript.

This is the function I'm using
How to execute it after page load and is that the right way to remove an element?

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post CODE, not pictures of code

Comment: Notice that getElements is plural so either `parent =  myDiv[0].parentNode` or simpler using [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove): `document.querySelector('.data-ex-icons-layers').remove()` or if you have more: `[...document.querySelectorAll('.data-ex-icons-layers')].forEach(ele => ele.remove())`